# Iframe check for the successful response on form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have been trying to embed Iframe in my react js project. The issue i am facing is that the source of Iframe is an external url which returns HTML form.

So is there any way on how could I check whether the submission of form was successful or not based on the HTML template return by them in the response.